# Mac Os Server, how to make bind point www.mydomain.com to the same machine bind is installed on?

Tags: bind, mac-osx-server, mac-osx

I want to set my server's IP as DNS and then be able to to make domains like myproject.com, and also www.myproject.com, and *.applications.com point to the same server where I will be hosting these files in apache.

I installed macports, and here is my configuration file:
/opt/local/etc/named.conf

```
    // Declares control channels to be used by the rndc utility.
    //
    // This must be enabled on Mac OS X Server for Server Status to provide valid
    // information! (Remove the leading slashes to enable.)
    //
    //        **** STUFF YOU MIGHT NEED TO ENABLE ****
    //
     controls {
          unix "/var/run/ndc" perm 0600 owner 0 group 0;
          inet 127.0.0.1 port 54 allow {any; };
     };
    // It is recommended that 127.0.0.1 be the only address used.
    // This also allows non-privileged users on the local host to manage
    // your name server.

    options {
            directory "/opt/local/var/named";

            // uncomment the following lines to turn on DNS forwarding,
            // and change the forwarind ip address(es) :
            //forward first;
            //forwarders {
            //      123.123.123.123
            //      123,123.123.123;
            //};

            listen-on-v6 { none; };
            listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };

            // to allow only specific hosts to use the DNS server:
            //allow-query {
            //      127.0.0.1;
            //};

            dnssec-validation auto;
            pid-file "/opt/local/var/run/named.pid";
    };

    //
    // a caching only nameserver config

    zone "." IN {
            type hint;
            file "db.cache";
    };

    zone "localhost" IN {
            type master;
            file "db.localhost";
            allow-update { none; };
    };

    zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
            type master;
            file "db.127.0.0";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
```

So I wanna be able to make all these point to the same server where bind is installed:

```
www.myproject.com
myproject.com
*.applications.com
```

How can I do this? I would also like to ask how can I get a good documentation or book about bind. The documents I found on web were either too technical or too simplistic.

Or is there an easier interface to work with bind?

Comment: As for bind guides - there's excellent (and free) DNS for Rocket Scientists: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ and Oreilly's DNS and BIND is great.

Comment: That book is pretty hardcore, not suitable for someone who doesn't wanna be a dns Einstein, but only wants to make the thing work once and for all, It seems to be the most popular book on bind though, many thanks for sharing

Comment: Oreilly's first chapters are quite simple how-to with an example of config file and zone. Should be enough to start with. I think there's some GUI for bind, maybe it doesn't work on mac. And doesn't macos have it's own DNS server ?

Comment: Btw, if you want it easy, why not to use some hosted DNS service ? like freedns.afraid.org. - should be easier and more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit you named.conf to add a zone like:

```
zone "myproject.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "myproject.com.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
}
```

Then create a zone file in `/opt/local/var/named` named `myproject.com.zone`. That file should look like:

```
$ORIGIN myproject.com.
$TTL 21600 
@                      3600 SOA   <your ns A record>. (
                              sysadmins.stackoverflow.com.    ; address of responsible party
                              2011072601                          ; serial number
                              3600                       ; refresh period
                              600                        ; retry period
                              604800                     ; expire time
                              60                       ) ; minimum ttl
                                NS    <YOUR_NS_A_RECORD>.

                                A     <YOUR_IP>
*               IN      A     <YOUR_IP>
```

Wildcarding it is you best options since you then don't have to worry about it again.

I highly recommend getting a copy of [DNS and BIND](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100574)

Comment: Thank you Zypher, can you tell me how I can find my ns A record?

Comment: You need to set it in your zone file - if everything is under `<YOUR_IP>` then the `*` will cover you (however you should really manually specify it as `nsX    IN    NS    <IP>`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the zone file, I used what Zypher suggested in named.conf

```
$TTL 10800
myproject.com. IN SOA myservername.myproject.com. admin.mymyproject.com. (
    2011071800  ;Serial
    86400       ;Refresh
    3600        ;Retry
    604800      ;Expire
    345600      ;Negative caching TTL
 ) 

www.projects.com. IN  A <SERVER IP>
projects.com. IN  NS myservername.myproject.com. 
projects.com. IN  A <SERVER IP> 
www IN  CNAME myproject.com.
```