# Make server use it's own DNS first to resolve domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, bind

I have a bind server setup on my mac OS lion,

And I have a few domains like myproject.com point to the same server using the configurations here:

[Mac Os Server, how to make bind point www.mydomain.com to the same machine bind is installed on?](https://serverfault.com/questions/334920/mac-os-server-how-to-make-bind-point-www-mydomain-com-to-the-same-machine-bind/335063#335063)

I have a few windows machines in my LAN, I have setup their DNS server addresses as follows

```
Preferred DNS Server 192.168.2.25 << my server's IP
Alternative DNS Server 192.168.2.1 << my Router
```

Here is a screenshot of my windows preferences,

[image: windows dns preferences]

Everything works as expected, when I ping myproject.com from my windows machine, it resolves to 192.168.2.25

Now the problem is, the server itself is not configured to use it's own DNS, so when I ping myproject.com it resolves to 68.178.232.99 which is the actual IP address of myproject.com on Internet.

Here is a screen shot of how I have tried to setup the server to use it's own DNS server in
System Preferences -> Network -> Ethernet -> Advanced -> DNS

[image: dns server settings on mac os lion]

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to make this server look at it's own DNS first and then look at the router's DNS when trying to resolve a domain name?

gateway.2wire.net is the default value for search domains.

Thanks,
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to solve this would probably be to set your DNS server to *only* use localhost for DNS lookups, and configure your bind server as a [forwarder to your upstream DNS server](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch4/#forwarding).

Comment: Shouldn't this work without having to do that?

Comment: No, it shouldn't work without that, even with windows strictly speaking it shouldn't work. You need to allow forwarding OR allow recursion, and use this server only.

Comment: Nope, this is the only practical way to go. The list of DNS servers in an operating system is not a "check this first, if that fails, check that"... it's a list of servers of equal "rank" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a static hosts file entry is the way to go. Setup nsswitch to look up against local hosts file first and you should be OK.